# Which of the following relations are functions of q?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Firstly, what is a function of q? Am I correct to assume it means $f(q)$?

$w=q+1$ For this one, it is a linear function, so it has to be a function of q.  But I'm not sure how to express it?

$wq=-27$ Again, $w=\frac{-27}{q}$ This is a linear function? So it has to be a function?

$sin(w) = q^2$ I am not sure for this one.

All I've learned about functions is $f(x)$ notation.  So I am not sure how I am supposed to see these questions?

How do I turn the above relations into functions of q?

Comment: Is there some domain given for $q$? E.g. something like $q>0$ or $q\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: No, all the question states is "Which of the following relations are functions of q:"

Comment: All of them are functions of $q$. But there should be some restrictions on $q$ for second and third one. Meanly for second one $q\neq0$ and for third one $q\in[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is an answer for $sin(w)=q^2$:**

In order to express $w$ as a function of $q$, you need to apply $\arcsin$ on both sides of the equation.

This gives you $w=\arcsin(q^2)$.

This function is defined only in the domain $q\in[-1,1]$, and its range is $w\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$.

[image]

Comment: Ah yes, and it's not a function because arcsin can return multiple values, i.e. arcsin of 0 is $k\pi$ where k is an integer.

Comment: @Jason: Please read the answer a little more carefully. It's a function in the specified domain.